# Proving Variance of Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

My question is as follows: using the standard integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$
prove directly from the definition that the variance of the normal distribution,
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}},$$ is $\sigma^2$. It is important to note that no understanding of why the integral above is true is needed to answer the question. I am instructed that integration by parts is required, but I'm struggling...

---

Ok, I've tried with much help from you lot, thanks greatly, but have missed something:

$$\begin{align}Var(X) &= E((X-\mu)^2) \\
& = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x-\mu)^2e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx \\ & Let\;y = \frac{(x-\mu)}{\sigma} \\ & = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}dx \\
&=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}([ue^{-\frac{1}{2}u^2}]_{-\infty}^{\infty}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}u^2}du)
\\ &=\sigma
\end{align}$$
where did I go wrong?

Comment: Did you try integrating by parts? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: For any pdf $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = 1$

Comment: @carmichael561 to find the variance I need $E(X^2)$, so integrating that is the problem for me.

Comment: @DougM: It can absolutely be solved using integration by parts

Comment: @Gentleman_Narwhal: assuming you know the mean is $\mu$, it's better to use $\mathrm{var}(X)=\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^2]$.

Comment: @DougM I am informed the solution does not involve multivariable calculus. As far as I can see I use $Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$.

Comment: Hint: to calculate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 e^{-ax^2}\,dx$, integrate by parts with $u = x$, $dv = x e^{-ax^2}\,dx$.

Comment: @carmichael561 How do I get an integral from $E((X-\mu)^2)$?

Comment: Differentiating (wrt $a$) under the integral is, I believe, known as “Feynman's trick”. However, its rigorous application may be beyond the level of many first year students.

Comment: @Gentleman_Narwhal: use the pdf

Comment: @DanielSchepler But is the $uv$ part not $[\frac{1}{-2a}xe^{-ax^2}]^{\infty}_{-\infty}$ - which I cannot solve?

Comment: @carmichael561 - please explain further ...

Comment: The variance is equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x-\mu)^2e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\;dx$. I suggest first making the change of variables $y=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$, then you can integrate by parts.

Comment: $[\frac{1}{-2a}x^2e^{-ax^2}]^{\infty}_{-\infty}$ is your sticking point?  $\lim_\limits{x\to \infty} p(x) e^{-x} = 0$ for any polynomial.  The exponential goes to $0$ more powerfully than the polynomial grows.

Comment: @DougM Ah yes, I recall that coming up - thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your substitution step is lacking an extra factor of $\sigma$ because you should have written $$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty (x-\mu)^2 e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)} \, dx &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} \int_{y=-\infty}^\infty (\sigma y)^2 e^{-y^2/2} \sigma \, dy \\
&= \frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{y=-\infty}^\infty y^2 e^{-y^2/2} \, dy.
\end{align*}$$  This is because $y = (x-\mu)/\sigma$ implies $x = \sigma y + \mu$, hence $dx = \sigma \, dy$.